# How do i convert XLS file with ; delimiter to CSV file in Python ? It would be good if you provide a example script

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

I want to write a Python script that reads in an Excel spreadsheet and saves some of its worksheets as CSV files.

How can I do this?

I tried to do my own code, see it below.

```
import xlrd
import csv

   def csv_from_excel():

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('ArquivoAgencias.xls')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('AGENCIA')
    AgenciaFile = open('AgenciaFile.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(AgenciaFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    AgenciaFile.close()
```

But i don`t know how i convert the XLS file with ; delimiter to CSV, i appreciate if anyone have any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) and [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Martijn - I hope you don't mind if I use that as a template for my responses as well.

Comment: Thanks Martijn and Matthias. Post Edited.

Comment: What do you mean by *XLS file with ; delimiter* ? The above code will generate a CSV file correctly... What is the output you're getting and how does it differ from what you'd expect?

Comment: Jon, the code generate a CSV file with "," collumns delimiter and i need the ";" as delimiter.

Comment: @TadeuDrub oh... use: `wr = csv.writer(AgenciaFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=';')` then...